# Ubuntu 16.04 running on low graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics, lightdm

A problem with my computer graphics mode. Before the low graphics problem , whenever I entering into GUI I see an error as " app armor intialization : LSB " which goes off in seconds
and then I will get GUI login as usual. after the usual login, I checked my SE linux status which is in permissive mode, early it was in enforcing mode. but after making it in enforcing mode, low graphics mode error started to occur.

four options I got,

1) try to start with normal graphics mode
2) Reconfigure
3) troubleshoot error
4) exit to console login.

1st option starts the process again to low graphics mode.... it does nothing

2nd option reconfigure takes me to two set of options

2a) generic system
2b) backedup config

both does nothing .. not even a react

3rd option troubleshoot error takes me to 3 option

3a) show startup error
3b) show error log
3c) seriously I forgot the 3rd option in this issue.

but those 3 also doesn't react a bit.

4th option exit to console login

4a) goes to tty1 login... but when i tried to enter with correct username and password, console logouts immediately with a second

After the lot of searching,

I updated graphics driver from Xorg video-intel .. but ubuntu said graphics is updated.

when i tried to look /etc/X11/Xorg.conf .. actually there is no file exist so i created it with some commands from stackover flow..

Now that file also doesn't exist. Instead it has a file called xorg.conf.failsafe

and that file has the following thing

```
Section "Device"
Identifier    "Configured Video Device"
Driver        "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier    "Default Screen"
Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
Device        "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Now I installed GDM . now its prompting me to use single display manager program. I am waiting to press okay for it, still didn't press it.

And this is my lscpu

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4160 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3594.796
CPU max MHz:           3600.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              7183.69
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

and my computer lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
```

Currently am writing this post via recovery mode dpkg option, all other options doesn't make my day luck.

if I come out of recovery this dpkg recovery option

again the Low graphics mode problem starts.?

Can anybody help me out the trouble ?

I am waiting for the reply without shutting down the system, because entering in to the dpkg recovering options is kind of big work for me i felt.

Comment: Modern Xorg can auto-configure the graphics card, so an explicit configuration file is very rarely needed. This is quite the contrast from what it was like before, when you needed to set things up manually including modelines for your monitor and all kinds of other funny (but awfully tedious) things. Of course, autodetection sometimes gets it wrong. I would **suggest** moving /etc/X11 out of the way entirely and doing a `dpkg-reconfigure` on the relevant packages, but that's assuming that Ubuntu is similar enough to Debian in this regard. (It might be, or not.)

Comment: Also note that [unix.se] is geared toward all Linux distributions as well as Unixes. You may get more Ubuntu-esque answers if you instead ask on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). You can flag your question for moderator attention and request migration if you wish.

Comment: @michael Kjorling , do you want me to run dpkg-reconfigure on etc/X11

Comment: No, you would run `dpkg-reconfigure` on the X11 packages. I don't know what the names of those are on Ubuntu.